# How to call block function in other custom module's model file?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am working on Magento 2. I want to use other module's block function to get some data. How can I call that block function in my module's model file ?

Comment: Add the code of your modules model file

Answer (score 0):

The two ways to call you a block class method in custom module class

1) using constructor dependency
like that

```
   public function __construct(Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data $helper)
   {
           $this->helper = $helper;
   }
   public function MyFunction()
   {               $this->helper->HelperDemo();
   }
```

2) using method dependency
    public function execute(Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data $helper)
    {
                    $helper->HelperDemo();
    }

for more detail visit the below link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html